# Deleting a table in phpMyAdmin without accessing its content

Tags: phpmyadmin, web-hosting

I have a web hosting with a limited access and I have to delete a number of tables.
I am getting the following error while deleting tables one after the other:

```
user has exceeded the 'max_queries_per_hour'
```

I assume that this error is due to the fact that while I am pointing to a table to delete it its records are loaded.

Is there a way to delete a table in phpMyAdmin without accessing its content?

Comment: This site suggests you can multi-select tables and batch drop them: https://www.servercake.blog/delete-multiple-tables-database-using-phpmyadmin/

Comment: @geonaut thank you for the link but it wont work since there is no checkbox to select tables. I found a way to do it by sql querying in the console window: DROP TABLE database.table and it works.

Comment: The error is more about a server restriction that limits the number of queries you can run in a one hour period instead of working with a table that's open. Databases generally deal quite well with concurrent access (with exceptions for table or row locking for specific operations, but those are usually very brief). Having the table "open" for viewing shouldn't affect your ability to delete or insert data. If you really want to remove all data but keep the table's structure, you could use TRUNCATE instead of DROP.